# Branching lost after merge

Tags: git

My work flow: Branch > do some work (on branch) > test (branch) > checkout master > pull (make sure master is up to date) > merge (my branch into master) > push

Normally i this will result in a timeline where a branch comes out of master then returns back into master. This is visualised nicely in Sourcetree.

Last two branches have for some reason been squished into master after the merge. It looks as if i commited directly into master and not into my branch. 
I there some setting i my have inadvertedly set?

I use Sourcetree to see what is going on and for commits. The rest (pushing, pulling, branching, merging) i usually do commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature is called "fast forward". You'll want to add the option `--no-ff` to disable it:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff mybranch
```

See `git help merge` for more details.